# Do the 7 trumpets in Revelation 8:6 allude to Joshua 6:13?

Tags: revelation, joshua

Joshua 6:

> 13
> The seven priests carrying the **seven trumpets** went forward, marching before the ark of the LORD and blowing the trumpets. The armed men went ahead of them and the rear guard followed the ark of the LORD, while the trumpets kept sounding.

Revelation 8:

> 6
> Then the seven angels who had the **seven trumpets** prepared to sound them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can see common between the Joshua's seven trumpets and the Revelation's seven trumpets is the the phrase "seven trumpets".  Other than this incidental phrase, they have nothing in common.

However, the seven trumpets of Revelation appear to have as their object the reverse order of Gen 1 creation.  Indeed, there are a number of significant difference between the two accounts:

| Joshua 6 seven trumpets | Revelation 8-11 seven trumpets |
| --- | --- |
| Sounded simultaneously | Sounded sequentially |
| Applied locally at Jericho in a single place | Applied widely over and to much greater objects such as trees, sun moon and stars, rivers and seas, etc. |
| Jericho completely destroyed and all people killed | One third of creatures or objects are destroyed |
| Trumpets sounded in the presence of the Ark of the Covenant | Ark of the Covenant is revealed only AFTER the trumpets sound (Rev 11:19) |
| "trumpets" are שׁוֹפָר shophar = ram's horn and always used in Israel's battles and announcements (Ex 19:16, 19, 20:18, Lev 23:24, 25:9, Judges 3:27, etc, as distinct from the silver trumpets (חֲצֹצְרָה Chatsotserah, Num 10:2, 5, 7, 8, 29:1, etc) associated with the temple | Trumpets are associated with the temple because the angels come from the temple, Rev 8:2-6 |

Thus, Joshua's trumpets serve a very different function and have a different origin from Revelation's trumpets.

**APPENDIX - Analysis of the seven trumpets:**

**Introductory Vision** Rev 8:2-6: “And I saw…”

**A:** the seven angels who stood before God and there were given to them seven trumpets

. **B:** And another angel came and stood on the altar having a golden censer

. . **C:** And there was given to him much incense(s) so that he will give [it] with the prayers of the saints

. . . **D:** all on the golden altar before the throne

. . **C:** And the smoke of the incense(s) went up with the prayers of the saints out of the hand of the angel

. **B:** And the angel took the censer and filled it with fire from the altar,
and cast [it] into the earth and there occurred thunders and rumblings and lightings and [an] earthquake

**A:** And the seven angels having the seven trumpets prepared themselves to trumpet.

| Agent of Trumpet | Object | Result of Trumpet |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Three Trumpets of Fire** |  |  |
| **1**. Hail and fire mixed with blood Rev 8:7 | Hurled on the land | * One third of earth burned * One third of trees burned * All green grass burned |
| **2**. Something like a huge mountain ablaze Rev 8:8, 9 | Hurled into sea | * One third of sea turned to blood * One third of sea creatures die * One third of ships destroyed |
| **3**. Great star (Wormwood) blazing like a torch falls from heaven to earth. Rev 8:10, 11 | rivers and springs of waters | * One third of rivers turned bitter * Many people die of the bitter waters |
| **Celestial Trumpet** |  |  |
| **4**. [Divine decree??] | Sun, Moon and Stars | * One third of sun darkened * One third of moon darkened * One third of stars darkened * One third of day without light * One third of night without light |
| **Three Trumpets of Woe** |  |  |
| **5**. Star (angel and king of locusts) fallen from heaven to earth with key to abyss opens it. Smoke rises as from a great furnace and become locusts. Rev 9:1–11 | Earth | * Sun and air darkened |
| **6**. Voice from the horns of the golden altar commands the four angels bound at the Euphrates to release an army of 200,000,000 mounted troops, prepared for the hour, day, month & year (Rev 9:13–21) | Euphrates River | * One third of mankind killed by fire, smoke and sulphur * Remainder of mankind not killed by three plagues: - did not repent of works of their hands - did not stop worshipping demons and idols - did not repent of murders, sorcery, fornication, thefts |
| **7**. Loud voices in heaven proclaim Rev 11:14–18 | Kingdoms of this world | * Kingdoms of this world have become the kingdom of God and of His Christ * 24 elders worshipped God and gave thanks * God begins eternal reign * Nations angry * Judgement begins |